# How do I avoid Git's `--fork-point` becoming confused by a retroactively created branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

When I find that I should've made a branch for my current changes, I usually do something along the lines of

```
$ git switch -t -c new-branch
$ git switch master # switch back
$ git reset --hard origin/master # assume I had no staged changes
$ git switch new-branch
```

But then if I pull some external changes into `master` and then try to `git rebase` my `new-branch` (which uses `--fork-point` by default), it will just erase everything and reset it to the new `master`.

Can I do the retroactive branch creation part differently in order to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is *not* to use the `--fork-point` option, e.g. by adding `--no-fork-point` at the end of the `rebase` command.

If that's not an option, since the `--fork-point` uses the *reflog* of the **master** branch, this reflog has to be modified. The command below prunes entries in the reflog of the **master** branch that are not reachable from the tip of **master**. Note that this is a destructive operation, it is not limited to the commits in **new-branch** and you may lose other log data by doing this.

```
git reflog expire --expire=never --expire-unreachable=all master
```

The whole workflow then looks like this:

```
# we don't need to switch back-and-forth
git branch -t new-branch

# reset to upstream
git reset --hard @{u}

# prune reflog
git reflog expire --expire=never --expire-unreachable=all master
```